# SVG from web form to print c#?How to

Tags: c#, asp.net, svg

I have svg code in my asp.net page

```
<svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <g>
    <title>background</title>
     <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="402" width="582"y="-1"x="-1"/>

     <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%"width="100%"id="canvasGrid">

      <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" 
   width="100%"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
 <path id="svg_1" 
 d="m112.9375,236.28002l18.375,-92.00001l61.25,0l18.37499,92.00001l-98,0z" 
 stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
 <path id="svg_2" d="m265.17247,210.49499l0,-109l101.00002,109l-
 101.00002,0z" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Now i want to print this using c# may be as pdf or png is there any way ?

Comment: [Aspose](https://www.aspose.com/)

Comment: I need code like [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dflor003/kmr5w3x1/) but it is not integrating

Answer (score -1):

Install PhantomJS on the webserver and use "rasterize.js" to render the SVG (or HTML) code as PDF on the server.